# How to change The theme of Windows form application in C#

Tags: c#, windows, forms, c#-4.0, window

I am trying to get rid of the default theme of window form application and want to changed it to be better look one in C# I have searched in google but found no result.
Is there any library which I use  to make a good look window form application?
If there is would you please share the link with me.

thanks in advance.

Comment: In Windows Forms not without a library, but it's possible in WPF. About the library: **Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic** for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.

Comment: try use this one  - http://www.skin-soft.co.uk/Products/VisualStyler/Overview.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had this need and I found the Metroframework library.
https://www.nuget.org/packages/MetroFramework/

with few changes you will have a good change in the visual.

after install go to designer class and modify this:

```
public partial class frmTeste : form
```

to:

```
public partial class frmTeste : MetroForm
```

and you will see the diference.

Comment: Comments use mini-Markdown formatting: [link](http://example.com) _italic_ **bold** `code`. The post author will always be notified of your comment. To also notify a previous commenter, mention their user name: @peter or @PeterSmith will both work. Learn more about formatting…